# Combine two functions with AND

Tags: jquery

I use the two scripts to disable a submit button, if either the select is selected (script 1) OR the link is clicked (script 2).

I need them to be depended of each other with AND, so both have to be changed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

  $('.wc-pao-addon-field').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") === 0) {
      $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.wc-pao-addon-laagfarve a').click(function() {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You seem to be expecting to join two events together, but that's obviously not possible. Do you mean that you need the user to fire both events before the button becomes enabled?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the user have to both select from the dropdown and click the link.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `button` enabled only after the link has been clicked and an option has been chosen from the `select` you can execute the same logic block after both events. That logic can check for a `class` which has been placed on the `a` as well as the `selectedIndex` of the select, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $btn = $('.single_add_to_cart_button');

  var $select = $('.wc-pao-addon-field').on('change', function() {
    setSubmitState();
  });

  var $a = $('div.wc-pao-addon-laagfarve a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    setSubmitState();
  });

  function setSubmitState() {
    $btn.prop('disabled', $select.prop('selectedIndex') == 0 || !$a.hasClass('active'));
  }
});
```

```css
a.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wc-pao-addon-laagfarve">
  <select class="wc-pao-addon-field">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
  </select>
  <a href="#">Click me</a>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button" disabled>Add to cart</button>
```

Note in the jQuery example above that you can place all logic within a single document.ready event handler.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanation and code - will try to get it to work on my site. Will get back...

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a class to the body during each event.  Then you can check for that class during one event to verify the other fired already.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

  $('.wc-pao-addon-field').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
        $('body').addClass('select-change');
        if ($('body').hasClass('button-clicked') {
            $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        }
      });

    $('div.wc-pao-addon-laagfarve a').click(function() {
        $('body').addClass('button-clicked');
        if ($('body').hasClass('select-change') {
            $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
    });
});
```